# supervisor cannot watch template files' change in node express

Tags: node.js, express-4

My Express version is 4.x

I use this command to run the express app:

```
$ DEBUG=express_app:* supervisor bin/www
```

And everything goes well!

But when I only modified the template files in `views/` ,and then refresh the browser, the page doesn't change unless I restart the server.

How can I solve this. Is there any solutions?